# Python 3.5 can not open a url- error (http 403)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to open and parse the following URL in Python 3.5 for to collect some of the comments for my assignment. This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request ("http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-35-Zoloft+oral.aspx?drugid=35&drugname=Zoloft+oral&conditionFilter=-500")    
home_page = urlopen(req).read()
print (home_page)
```

And this is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/maryamzolnoori/Dropbox/Dissertation/Programming/Web-Crawl/Askapatient_collect_comments.py", line 12, in <module>
        home_page = urlopen(req).read()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I tested it even in python 2.7 and it failed. The error is:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a 403 forbidden, most likely due to the user agent being python. Try setting the user agent as if you are a browser.

For example:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = "http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-35-Zoloft+oral.aspx?drugid=35&drugname=Zoloft+oral&conditionFilter=-500"
req = Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

home_page = urlopen(req)
print(home_page.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Also a good idea to use the appropriate encoding.